# Where can I find a 5/16" end cap for a faucet diverter?

Tags: plumbing, fitting

I have a Delta kitchen faucent with a diverter shank that connects to a hose for a pullout sprayer. I am disconnecting it because I want to use the sprayer hole for a filtered water faucet. The problem is that the hose connects to the shank via a 5/16" fitting. I have disconnected the hose and need to find an end cap that will screw onto the shank.

I showed the hose to a plumber who happened to be at Home Depot (another customer, not a staff guy) and he says, "Oh, that's a standard 3/8" fitting", then I say, "No its 5/16th", then he says, "No such thing, its 3/8ths". Then we go over to the fittings and find a male 3/8" plug and sure enough its slightly too big for the hose. He's like "Damn, its 5/16th". So he directs me to a plumbing supply store. I go there. The guy is like "We have no 5/16th anything".

I have a lathe, do I need to get some hex rod and cut my own internal 5/16" diameter thread. I hope not because I hate cutting internal threads, especially into a blind hole. Please tell me there is somewhere I can get a 5/16" brass end cap. Note that an adapter will do just as well, because if I can get a 5/16" to 3/8" adapter, then I can use a 3/8" end cap, which Home Depot does have.

Comment: Have you tried [google](https://www.google.com/) ("*5/16 in. brass cap*")? [5/16" Brass Flare Cap](http://www.supplyhouse.com/Jones-Stephens-F40-098-40-5-5-16-Brass-Flare-Cap?gclid=CNiqqdTGkMACFcI7MgodIwUAcA)

Comment: I did try Google and Amazon and MSC and McMaster Carr. Maybe using the wrong search term or something.

Comment: Shop for me questions are considered off-topic since they are only likely to help someone in the exact same region as you.

Comment: @Steven actually I ended up ordering it from Amazon, so it is not a regional question, is it?

Comment: Yes it still is.  Amazon offers different products to different regions.  They might offer it today but not tomorrow, hence its unlikely to help the broad audience of the site in the longer term.

Comment: Heh, you are too late, I already got an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was using the right search terms. Based on Tester101's comment I tried some additional terms, especially "flare". Although I did not originally want a flare cap, it helped improve the search results enormously so I was able to find the right kind of suppies and narrow down to something that would work. Ultimately I got this:

[5/16 Brass SAE 45 Degree Flare Tube Fitting Cap - 5-Pack](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IRG0K8Q)

[image: 5/16" brass flare cap]